# why the 2d array is rewritten after generation

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have method generateWeights() for geting random values in array;
And mathod learn() that called method changeWeights() that change values on array.

**Expected:** before call method learn() on console.log() I will get array with random values

**Actually:** on this console.log I already array from nex line on method changeWeights()

Code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Letters} from "../constnants/letters";
import {Alphabet} from "../constnants/alphabet";
import {GeneralWeights} from "../constnants/weights";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LearningService {
  public theta: number = 0;
  letters = new Array<number[][]>();
  d: number = 0;
  weights: number[][] = [[]];

  constructor() {
    this.initTheta();

    this.initArrays();

    this.weights = this.generateWeights(7, 5);
    
    console.log('On this log I expect to get generated values: ', this.weights);

    this.learn();
  }

  public learn(): void {

    for (let n = 0; n < Alphabet.ALPHABET.length; n++) {
      let counter;
      while (true) {
        counter = n;
        for (let i = n; i < Alphabet.ALPHABET.length; i++) {

          this.d = Alphabet.ALPHABET[i] === Alphabet.ALPHABET[n] ? 1 : 0;

          console.log("checking ", Alphabet.ALPHABET[i], ': ');
          const x = this.letters[i];
          const res: boolean = this.isRight(this.getSum(x));

          if ((i !== n  && res) || (i === n && !res)) {
            i--;
            this.changeWeights(x, res, this.d);

            console.log('');
          } else {
            GeneralWeights.WEIGHTS.push(this.weights);
            counter++;
          }
          if(counter === 33) {
            console.log(GeneralWeights.WEIGHTS);
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }

  comparisonSum(twoDimensionalArray: number[][], index: number): number {
    let sum = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    twoDimensionalArray.forEach(array => {
      j = 0;
      array.forEach(item => {
        i = 0;
        sum += item * GeneralWeights.WEIGHTS[index][i][j];
        j++;
      })
      i++;
    })
    return sum;
  }

  generateWeights(rows: number, cols: number): number[][] {
    return Array.from({ length: rows }).map(() =>
      Array.from({ length: cols }).map(() => Math.random())
    );
  }

  public getSum(x: number[][]): number{
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++){
      for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        sum += x[i][j] * this.weights[i][j];
      }
    }
    console.log("sum = ", sum);
    return sum;
  }

  public isRight(sum: number): boolean {
    return sum >= this.theta;
  }

  private changeWeights(x: number[][], y: boolean, d: number): void {
    console.log("New weights: ");
    let ni = 2.5;
    let e = d - (y ? 1 : 0);

    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        // this.weights[i][j] += ni * e * x[i][j];
        this.weights[i][j] = 0;

      }
    }
    console.log(this.weights);
  }

  private initTheta(): void {
    this.theta = Math.random() * 2 -1;
    console.log('θ = ', this.theta);
    console.log('');
  }

  private initArrays(): void {
    for (let letters of Letters.LETTERS) {
      this.letters.push(letters)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: At all the voters for closing this question. Be fair! With a little good will you surly can understand the core of his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the browser console adjusts the array when it changes due to the code. At least as long as you don't clone it and break the reference to it.

Try your `console.log()` this way:

```
console.log('On this log I expect to get generated values: ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.weights)));
```

Doing this you see its original state before calling `learn()`.

Comment: on console log it works, thank you! But for me intersting, how to properly clone these arrays so that they are not overwritten by reference and etc..

Comment: PS: If you found my solution useful. please mark it as solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry for asking again. You upvoted the question. Many thanks for that.  But there is another button which marks the answer as solution.